# Optional JNDI Binding For Websphere Web Application

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

I would like to have **optionally** supplied information available to my webapp when deployed to Websphere (we are using 8.5) via the application's JNDI context.

I know that I can put a `resource-ref` or `resource-env-ref` in my web.xml but when I do that WAS will **require** me to supply a binding for it and deployment time.

My application will look in JNDI for certain values and adjust its behavior if found, but will function fine with default behaviour if it does not find values in JNDI. How, in WAS, do I supply a binding (just for a string or a URL) for my webapp without declaring a dependency on it in a `resource-ref` or `resource-env-ref` in my web.xml.

I know how to do this in Tomcat, I just put a `Environment` entry in the context.xml, like this:

```
<Environment 
    name="com.myorg.config" 
    value="http://localhost:8081/suff"
    type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `@Resource String lookupName;` to accomplish the same in a portable manner.  You will be prompted for a value at deployment time, but you can specify nothing, which will cause no value to be injected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem isn't with reading the value, I've got code that does it fine.  I need a way of optionally supplying it so that it doesn't trigger an extra step at deployment time.

Comment: Well, ok.  If you're just looking for something global, you can use a string binding: (1) http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tnam_view_bindings.html (2) http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/unam_rstring_namespace.html